# Running java program by considering import dependencies

Tags: java, import, uima

I have java file at location.

```
/root/Desktop/software/UIMA/yagogit/yodaqa/src/main/java/cz/brmlab/yodaqa/analysis/question/FocusGenerator.java
```

This file is part of entire project - [FocusGenerator.java](https://github.com/brmson/yodaqa/blob/master/src/main/java/cz/brmlab/yodaqa/analysis/question/FocusGenerator.java)

it is importing couple of classes from UIMA and few other packages. (I already configure UIMA on my system)

```
import org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException;
import org.apache.uima.fit.component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase;
import org.apache.uima.UimaContext;
import org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException;
import cz.brmlab.yodaqa.model.TyCor.LAT;
import cz.brmlab.yodaqa.provider.OpenNlpNamedEntities;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.lexmorph.type.pos.POS;
import de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.ner.type.NamedEntity;
```

While executing entire projects following readme file, it works well. But I wanted to test each individual program, like one mentioned above. When I try to compile using `javac` it gives error, `cannot find symbol` as below

```
ATByFocus.java:77: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ImplicitQLAT
location: class cz.brmlab.yodaqa.analysis.question.LATByFocus
            addFocusLAT(jcas, focus, "amount", null, 33914, 0.0, new ImplicitQLAT(jcas));
                                                                     ^
LATByFocus.java:83: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class LAT
location: class cz.brmlab.yodaqa.analysis.question.LATByFocus
            addFocusLAT(jcas, focus, text, pos, 0, 0.0, new LAT(jcas));
```

and so on.

What is correct way to execute this file. I tried it importing in eclipse to, but in eclipse too it could not be imported as project.

Comment: You *really, really, really* shouldn't be doing this as root. No, really.

Comment: @chiastic-security: thanks, will take care. how does it matter?

Comment: It's a bit like driving at 80mph with no seatbelt. You'll be fine as long as you don't crash... a huge part of the protection you get on a Linux system comes from doing your normal operations as an unprivileged user rather than as root, and that particularly applies to logging onto a graphical window system. Linux is a lot cleaner than Windows in allowing you to get your normal stuff done without root/administrator privileges.

Comment: @chiastic-security: thanks for let me knowing. will consider this.

Comment: How exactly did you call `javac`?

Comment: @vanje: as usual, 'javac filename.java', for my normal program, which does not have such import, works fine in this way

Comment: This seems to be the problem. If you want to use external JARs you have to provide the classpath to the JARs you want to use to the `javac` command via the "-cp" command line switch. See the documentation for `javac`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html. So the call would be for example `javac -cp /path/to/userjar1.jar:/path/to/usejar2.jar filename.java`.

Comment: @vanje: thanks, but there only .java file. please check it https://github.com/brmson/yodaqa/tree/master/src, https://github.com/brmson/yodaqa

Comment: @vanje: i tried this, `javac -cp /user1/Desktop/software/UIMA/yagogit/yodaqa/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar LATByFocus.java 
` but same number of error. here it is https://github.com/brmson/yodaqa/tree/master/gradle/wrapper

Comment: If you want to use some classes of an external project, the recommended way is to build the project JARs with the supported build tool. This seems to be Gradle here. And then use these JARs in your project. But this is not so easy only with `javac` alone. There are not only the JARs created by the build tool but also all the dependencies used by the yodaqa project. You have to include all these JARs in your classpath, too. So the best way would be to also use a build tool with automatic dependency resolution like Maven or Gradle for your own project.

Comment: You should learn more about how Java, the JVM, JARs and build tools like Maven and Gradle work. It's not so easy but it's worth it.

Comment: @vanje: yeah, maven dependencies are there. trying to figure out how it can be used to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to build pieces of YodaQA in isolation. I think it's much simpler to just work within YodaQA, but create your custom main class which will directly call the FocusGenerator or any other class you want.

To add another main class and execute it, you will need to add another gradle target. See build.gradle for a few examples already: tsvgs, biocrftrain, etc.